# Why is the dice pool splitting handled the way it is?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

In V20 the rules say that a character can split his dice pool as many times as he likes to try to fit a few actions in one turn at the expense of rolling only 1/2 for two, 1/3 for three actions etc. However, the rules also state that if a character uses two or more different dice pools for two different actions, he uses the smaller one for both of them. To illustrate, a character with Dexterity 4, Firearms 4 and Driving 2, would have Dice Pool of 8 for shooting and 6 for driving. Shooting while driving would then require him to throw a half the smaller dice pool for both actions, giving him 3 dice on driving and again 3 on shooting.

Why is it written like that? I could give an example of a person hacking a computer who notices an enemy entering the room. Splitting actions to shoot the guy while hacking results in hilarity. A genius hacker (8) who is a terrible shot (2) would then get totally confused by the simplest code. On the other hand an assassin who can shoot with eyes closed (8) but poor at hacking (2) would inevitably miss the guy. I don't see how those actions influence each other in such a great way, especially since the distraction model has already been handled (1/2 of dice from whatever dice pool in question)

Can someone explain the rationale behind it? I know there has been an attempt at simplification of dice splitting, but why has this approach been chosen and not the one that has been (in my opinion) the most prevalent in WoD 2nd ed (split the actual dice pool for each action)?

Furthermore on the game with creatures being able to get an additional action per turn without splitting pools commonly regarded as OP in combat, I'd guess the intention would be to decrease the value of an additional action. Instead, by nerfing dice splitting the reverse seems to happen. How would that be justified?

Comment: If you don't like this method, you might prefer the new one they're putting in V:DA 20th. I've edited my answer to add it.

Comment: note that the mechanism was different in earlier versions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a "Designer Reasons" question (OT as of Meta), as the whole question is about the WHY

Comment: [Here's the relevant meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/questions-about-designer-reasons-are-off-topic) referenced above by Trish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your description of how dice pool splitting works isn't quite right; you don't have to halve the smallest die pool -- you can allot those dice over your actions as you see fit. From page 248:

> The player declares the total number of actions he
>   wishes his character to attempt and determines which
>   of those dice pools is the smallest. He may then allocate
>   that number dice among the actions as he sees fit.

Recall that splitting your die pool reflects doing both things in the same action — shooting *while* coding, or coding *while* shooting. I don't have the same trouble you do with the mounting difficulty of trying to do two wildly differing tasks simultaneously, especially if -- as you indicate -- one of them you're inept at. (A dice pool of 2 means either no skill at all or an Attribute of 1.) You should keep your eyes on the thing you actually know how to do.

As far as "why did the designers do it this way?" that information seems hard to find. With the move over to the new Onyx Path website, [the comments from that period seem to have been lost](http://theonyxpath.com/category/projects/vtm20/). However, you might be pleased to know that in the upcoming **Vampire: Dark Ages 20th Anniversary** edition, developer Olivia Hill has [crafted a new and different method for splitting die pools](http://theonyxpath.com/v20-dark-ages-combat-physical-disciplines/). [From the development document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10FUnyjTnV3iJjlEGrrN3PffdnBGlHOjVIbPc2ZUO32k/edit):

> Multiple Actions: If you need to take multiple actions in a turn, this must be decided before the first action you take. The first action is taken at +1 difficulty, with -1 dice. The second is at +2, with -2 dice. Each additional action increases in difficulty and decreases in dice. Multiple actions cannot be made if their difficulty would be 10 or higher or if they'd have zero dice.

Comment: For reference I will post the system in Revised Edition. In that edition, you have a malus of the total number of actions, and another -1 for each subsequent action. If you do two actions, there is a -2 to the first and a -3 to the second. Three actions? -3, -4 and -5. Four? -4, -5, -6 and -7, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

That way of splitting dice is how it was made on 2nd edition. On revised edition, the system was changed by one that don't let big pools being penalized for small ones. If they reverted to the original system, I think it was for simplicity, which means easier to understand and faster to apply.

Please don't be offended if I say that your example is not very inspired. Hacking and shooting happens on very different time scales, so it doesn't really makes much sense to split the dice. If I was hacking a computer and someone came to kill me, I would try to first shoot the guy, and continue hacking once my life is not in peril.

Anyway, that was the given example, I will try to reason with it.

**High computers, Low Firearms**

I am a software developer, but I have never shot a real weapon. If I had to make a program while shooting, I don't know if I would be able to write a ';' character. Firing would require such concentration I wouldn't be able to comfortably operate the computer.

**Low Computers, High Firearms**

The assassin has no knowledge of the system he is operating. Using it takes too much time for him, leaving her little time to properly point at her enemy.

That's a bit the key. If you are a very good driver and shooter, you can drive and shoot decently. If you are a terrible driver, you won't be able to get enough stability to make a decent shot. If you are a terrible shooter, pointing at your enemies will get your attention off the road.

That's why is better to do simultaneous things you do well, and to spend full time doing something that you don't.

If you're not convinced, try it yourself. Try to do two things, one you are very skilled, and one that you are not (like doing maths while swimming). Try and see if your lack of skill ruins both activities.